# If I have polygon data in shapefile, can I discretize the area into equidistant points?

Tags: pyqgis, polygon

If I have polygon data in shapefile, can I discretize the area into points?

e.g. a 3x3 polygon into 9 points. I tried MMQGIS - create grid layer and extract nodes, they produces messy things.

I use Python and QGIS

Comment: Will the points be used for further data processing purpose or just cartographic?

Comment: Can you provide an image of your data? Are all your polygons squares? A screen shot of what you consider 'messy things' would also be helpful, along with the settings you used.

Comment: Converting nodes into points is pretty simple, but it sounds like you want something like points distributed throughout the area of each polygon. It might help if you posted an image of your starting polygons and what you want the end result to look like.

Comment: I used the combination of 'qgis:creategrid'(1000 m x1000 m) and 'qgis:polygoncentroids' processing python methods for producing equidistant points into area of a polygon. I hope that it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I used the combination of 'qgis:creategrid'(1000 m x1000 m) and 'qgis:polygoncentroids' processing python methods for producing equidistant points into area of a polygon. Complete code is:

```
import processing

new_polygon = processing.getObjectFromName('new_polygon')

extent = new_polygon.extent()

xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax = extent.toRectF().getCoords()

extent = str(xmin)+ ',' + str(xmax)+ ',' +str(ymin)+ ',' +str(ymax) 

TYPE = 1
HSPACING = 1000
VSPACING = 1000

path = processing.runalg('qgis:creategrid', 
                         TYPE, 
                         extent, 
                         HSPACING,
                         VSPACING,
                         new_polygon.crs().authid(), 
                         None)

grid = QgsVectorLayer(path['OUTPUT'],
                      'grid',
                      'ogr')

path = processing.runalg('qgis:polygoncentroids',
                         grid,
                         None)

centroids = QgsVectorLayer(path['OUTPUT_LAYER'],
                           'centroids',
                           'ogr')

feat_centroids = [ feat for feat in centroids.getFeatures() ] 
feat_new_polygon = new_polygon.getFeatures().next()

new_feat_centroids = [ feat for feat in feat_centroids 
                       if feat.geometry().within(feat_new_polygon.geometry()) ]

uri = "Point?crs=" + new_polygon.crs().authid() + "&field=id:integer""&index=yes"

mem_layer = QgsVectorLayer(uri,
                           'point',
                           'memory')

prov = mem_layer.dataProvider()

for i, feat in enumerate(new_feat_centroids):
    feat.setAttributes([i])

prov.addFeatures(new_feat_centroids)

QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(mem_layer)
#QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(grid)
#QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(centroids)

del grid, centroids
```

After running above code at the Python Console of QGIS, with a polygon layer of next image, I got equidistant points into area of this layer.

[image]

Uncommenting these lines at the code and run it again:

```
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(grid)
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(centroids)
```

it's possible visualize the complete grid and centroids generated for corroborating adequate performance of code.

[image]

Comment: What can I do if I have a layer of polygons?